# JavaFx animation start/stop loop?

Tags: animation, javafx

is there anyway that you can start and stop an animation, so plays for 1 sec, stops for 1 sec? I have tried to implement this with a radio button toggle with thread.sleep, however I dont think its possible this way. Are there any other ways to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your animation:

```
Animation animation = ... ;
```

create a [`PauseTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) and place both in a [`SequentialTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html):

```
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
SequentialTransition seq = new SequentialTransition(animation, pause);
```

and then just play the sequential transition indefinitely (or as many times as you need):

```
seq.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
seq.play();
```

If you are using a `Timeline` as your animation, another approach is to add a key frame one second after the last key frame you have, that make no changes.